# is it possible to write a webapp that can download mails from exchange server 2007

Tags: scripting, imap, exchange-server-2007, mail-server

It does not matter what programming language. Can anyone please give me an idea if this is possible and any tools or API's available please?

Comment: With no constraints on programming language, I guess .NET should be acceptable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106212/programmatically-checking-for-outlook-e-mails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865267/access-exchange-e-mail-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973053/c-exchange-email-client http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211037/automated-processing-of-an-email-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117939/how-do-i-access-exchange-mailbox-from-asp-net-web-applicaion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you used the `imap` tag, I'm assuming that means that you have IMAP access to the server. In that case, then yes. There are several third-party components available that provide IMAP access in .NET code. I have personally used [RebEx Secure Mail for .NET](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/), and they provide a trial period where you can try it out and see if it will work for your purposes. There's also a fairly helpful help site.

For something free, try this: http://interimap.codeplex.com/

Comment: The price is too high for personal use. Any other options please? any open source?

Comment: @JPro: It was just an example. There are several other packages out there; Googling "C# IMAP" should get you started.